# Node, Express Static files and dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My static image can't be served on dynamic route.
I read multiple threads here , but none of the solutions worked.

```js
//The files in public work but those in the images folder dont
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'images');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(
      null,
      `${new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-')}` +
        '-' +
        file.originalname
    );
  }
});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));;

//My routes
 router.get('/user-page', isAuth, userRouter.getUserPage);
router.get('/user-page/:userId', isAuth, userRouter.getUserPage);
```

Comment: Make sure your urls are like `/images/image1.jpg` etc from your dynamic routes,

Comment: The urls when they work on my non dynamic routes look like this: http://localhost:3000/images/imageName.jpg and when im using dynamic routes it changes like this http://localhost:3000/user-pageUserId/images/imageName.jpg